# (Spring/JpaRepository ) Inheriting methods of JpaRepository from BaseEntityRepository to SubEntityRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

What would be the best practice for the following case?

You have the following entities:

```
@Entity public class BaseEntity { }
@Entity public class SubEntity extends BaseEntity { }
```

And you have a JpaRepository for BaseEntity having multiple select-methods:

```
public interface BaseEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<BaseEntity, Long> {
  Set<BaseEntity> findAll();
  Set<BaseEntity> findSome...();
}
```

Now you want a JpaRepository for SubEntity inheriting all the methods from BaseEntityRepository.

Now I imagine multiple scenarios, from whom I am not sure which one is the best or which ones should work:

(a) Create a new independent JpaRepository for SubEntity with exactly the same Methods, but substituing BaseEntity with SubEntity:

```
public interface SubEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SubEntity, Long> {
  Set<SubEntity> findAll();
  Set<SubEntity> findSome...();
}
```

(b) Extending BaseEntityRepository, all Methods should be inherited, but it still return BaseEntity-objects instead of SubEntity-objects

```
public interface SubEntity extends BaseEntityRepository {
}
```

I don't really like any of both solutions. How would you solve this?

Somehow I think JpaRepository is not ment for this use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parameterize your `BaseEntityRepository` and operate on those parameters.

```
public interface BaseEntityRepository<T, I> extends JpaRepository<T, I> {
  Set<T> findAll();
  Set<T> findSome...();
}
```

Then add any additional methods in the subclass by extending the `BaseEntityRepository`

```
public interface SubEntityRepository extends BaseEntityRepository<SubEntity, Long> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thx, but Eclipse tells me: "The type BaseEntityRepository is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <SubEntity, Long>" ... ok, I must add "<T, I>" after "BaseEntityRepository" as you told, I did skip that part ;)

Comment: Works as expected thx, but now I have another related question concerning @query:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543662/spring-jparepository-dynamic-query-when-inheriting-methods-of-jparepository