# (Spring/JpaRepository ) Dynamic @Query, when Inheriting methods of JpaRepository from BaseEntityRepository to SubEntityRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

*(This post continues the discussion from, the important parts are all repeated in-here:
[(Spring/JpaRepository ) Inheriting methods of JpaRepository from BaseEntityRepository to SubEntityRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426292/spring-jparepository-inheriting-methods-of-jparepository-from-baseentityrepos/61426576#61426576))*

Let's assume we have the following entities:

```
@Entity public class BaseEntity { }
@Entity public class SubEntity extends BaseEntity { }
```

and the following JpaRepository implemenations:

```
public interface BaseEntityRepository<T, I> extends JpaRepository<TableWithId, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT t FROM BaseEntity t WHERE id = :id")
    Optional<T> getById(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Query("SELECT t FROM BaseEntity t WHERE customField = :customField")
    List<T> findByCustomField(@Param("customField") String customField);
}
```

Now for the SubEntity I have another repo:

```
public interface SubEntityRepository extends BaseEntityRepository<SubEntity, Long> {}
```

Will JPA know that in @Query "BaseEntity" must be replaced by "SubEntity" and why?
If "no", how would be the best way to do what I want?

Comment: No. You are extending interface only

Comment: ok, but what would be the way of doing what I want here?

Comment: Create your methods in `SubEntityRepository`

Comment: Well this will contradict the polymorphism. Why should you be forced to reimplement queries in every subclass? Then there would be no interest in using JPA I guess ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SPEL

```
@Query("SELECT T FROM #{#entityName} T WHERE T.id = :id")
Optional<T> getById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but I have no idea why :-P
I don't even find something in https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html can you pls guide me in which direction do look? :)

Comment: @AndréPletschette Take a look here :) https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/spring-el.html

Comment: that's very useful thx, I just wonder why this is never used in examples ...